# iPad application: How to change image size with page orientation

Tags: ipad, resize, orientation, image

I am a completely new developer and have worked through various tutorials... How can I add an image to my home screen and have the attributes change along with the orientation? I've looked and seen some things but none have worked so far.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to provide more detail. What, exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found a webkit that worked!

> img.homepg {     width:920px; } @media screen and (max-width:910px)  {
>
> ```
> img.homepg { 
>     width:670px;  } } img { 
> transition:all .2s linear; 
> -o-transition:all .2s linear; 
> -moz-transition:all .2s linear; 
> -webkit-transition:all .2s linear; }
> ```

it was used to change text size when stretching a browser page,  but by changing text to an img tag it works wonders!